# Two models share one model (Post and Product share Category)

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a project that has some products. Each of these products belongs to a category. Now I have to add a post section to my project. Each post belongs to a category that clearly is different than product category. I want to know if there is a way to use that existing category for posts or not and I have to make a different model (e.g. PostCategory).

Comment: i think you have to use `polymorphic` relation check  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thank you @rkj. That was the first thing I tried but it doesn't work. My situation is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from this

Product Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Category', 'categorizable');
}
```

Post Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Category', 'categorizable');
}
```

Category Model

```
public function categorizable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

You category table should be like this

```
categories  (table)
    id - integer
    body - text
    categorizable_id - integer
    categorizable_type - string
```

Check details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations